# Android onTouchListener MotionEvent unwanted release

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have this code that performs action when I touch and release a button.
But turns out it releases immediately even though i'm not releasing it yet

```
switch (v.getId())

        {
        case(R.id.turnoffall):
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boffall2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pressed! ! !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boffall1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Released.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
}
```

how can I do this right?

Comment: have you tried to return a true after you handled the touch?

Comment: yup, .just the same,.

Comment: could you add the code you tried?

Comment: Tell me if my code works for you or not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this. I tested it. It works!

main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button:
                        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pressed! ! !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Released! ! !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just what i meant ;) THX myCode